# Fastest way to search string with two mismatch in big files in perl?

Tags: string, perl, search

I modified the code to work with two files. to_search.txt has string to be searched. big_file.fastq has lines where to be searched and if string found (2 mismatch allowed with exact length which range from 8-10, no addition and deletion), place in respective name. So each string is searched in all lines (2nd line) in big_file.fastq.

```
# to_search.txt: (length can be from 8-20 characters)

1       TCCCTTGT
2       ACGAGACT
3       GCTGTACG
4       ATCACCAG
5       TGGTCAAC
6       ATCGCACA
7       GTCGTGTA
8       AGCGGAGG
9       ATCCTTTG
10      TACAGCGC
#2000 search needed

# big_file.fastq: 2 billions lines (each 4 lines are associated: string search is in second line of each 4 lines). 
# Second line can have 100-200 characters
@M04398:19:000000000-APDK3:1:1101:21860:1000 1:N:0:1
TCttTTGTGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGGTCGTGTAGCCTCCAACCAAGCACCCCATCTGTTCCAAATCTTCTCCCACTGCTACTTGAAGACGCTGAAGTTGAAGGGCCACCTTCATCATTCTGG
+
#8ACCDGGGGGGGGGGGGGEGGGGGGGGDFFEGGG@FFGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGCF@<FFGGGGGFE9FGGGFEACE8EFFFGGGGGF9F?CECEFEG,CFGF,CF@CCC?BFFG<,9<9AEFG,,
@M04398:19:000000000-APDK3:1:1101:13382:1000 1:N:0:1
NTCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGTTCTGAGAGGTACCAACCAAGCACACCACGGGCGACACAGACAGCTCCGTGTTGAACGGGTTGTTCTTCTTCTTGCCTTCATCATCCCCATCCTCAGTGGACGCAGCTTGCTCATCCTTCCTC
+
#8BCCGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
@M04398:19:000000000-APDK3:1:1101:18888:1000 1:N:0:1
NCAGAATGAGGAAGGATGAGCCCCGTCGTGTCGAAGCTATTGACACAGCGCTATTCCGTCTTTATGTTCACTTTAAGCGGTACAAGGAGCTGCTTGTTCTGATTCAGGAACCGAACCCTGGTGGTGTGCTTGGTTGGCAAGTTTACGGCTC
+
#8BCCGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGCGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGFGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGE
```

Here is the code for two mismatches. I tried with exact match, speed is not bad: takes around a day. I have used Time::Progress module. When I use 2 mismatch: shows 115 days to finish. How the speed can be improved here?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$| = 1;

open( IN_P1, "big_file.fastq" ) or die "File not found";

my ( @sample_file_names, @barcode1 );
open( BC_FILE, "to_search.txt" ) or die "No barcode file";
my @barcode_file_content = <BC_FILE>;

foreach (@barcode_file_content) {
    chomp $_;
    $_ =~ s/\r//;
    $_ =~ s/\n//;

    #print $_;
    my @elements = split( "(\t|,| )", $_ );
    push @sample_file_names, $elements[0];
    push @barcode1,   $elements[2];
}

# open FH
my @fh_array_R1;
foreach (@sample_file_names) {
    chomp $_;
    local *OUT_R1;
    open( OUT_R1, ">", "$_\.fq" ) or die "cannot write file";
    push @fh_array_R1, *OUT_R1;
}

# unknown barcode file
open( UNKNOWN_R1, ">unknown-barcode_SE.fq" ) or die "cannot create unknown-r1 file";

while ( defined( my $firstp1 = <IN_P1> ) ) {

    my $p1_first_line  = $firstp1;
    my $p1_second_line = <IN_P1>;
    my $p1_third_line  = <IN_P1>;
    my $p1_fourth_line = <IN_P1>;

    chomp( $p1_first_line, $p1_second_line, $p1_third_line, $p1_fourth_line, );

    my $matched_R1 = "$p1_first_line\n$p1_second_line\n$p1_third_line\n$p1_fourth_line\n";

    for ( my $j = 0 ; $j < scalar @barcode1 ; $j++ ) {
        chomp $barcode1[$j];

        my $barcode1_regex = make_barcode_fragments( $barcode1[$j] );

        if ( $p1_second_line =~ /$barcode1_regex/i ) {
            # keep if matched
            print { $fh_array_R1[$j] } $matched_R1;
            last;
        }
        else {
            #print to unknown;
            print UNKNOWN_R1 $matched_R1;
        }
    }
}

# make two mismatch patterm of barcode
sub make_barcode_fragments {
    my ($in1) = @_;
    my @subpats;
    for my $i ( 0 .. length($in1) - 1 ) {
        for my $j ( $i + 1 .. length($in1) - 1 ) {
            my $subpat = join( '',
                substr( $in1, 0, $i ),
                '\\w', substr( $in1, $i + 1, $j - $i - 1 ),
                '\\w', substr( $in1, $j + 1 ),
            );
            push @subpats, $subpat;
        }
    }
    my $pat = join( '|', @subpats );

    #print $pat;
    return "$pat";
}
exit;
```

Comment: `Text::Levenshtein` might make if faster.

Comment: @Sobrique : This gives distance between strings. Here, one string is searched against another larger string, how the distance can be used here? Thanks

Comment: I am trying to understand the code: Why are you counting characters in the range (ASCII) 1-173 (octal 001-255)?

Comment: This looks like problems that appear often in bioinformatics. There are algorithms and programs implemented to align reads to reference sequences very quickly. For example bwa (https://github.com/lh3/bwa) implementing Burrow Wheeler transform. If this sounds like the right track and you get stuck you might want to ask for help on Biostars (https://www.biostars.org/).

Comment: @dariober : this is demultiplexing based on barcodes not the alignment.

Comment: You were previously given three solutions. I would have pegged this one as the slowest (unless it were to be converted into C)

Comment: You're calling `make_barcode_fragments` 4,000,000,000,000 times when it only needs to be called 2000!!! You'll also want to compile the patterns (using `qr//`) in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your algorithm cannot be changed/improved in Perl itself, you can still get speedup by writing the time consuming parts in C. Here is an example using inline C:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(timethese);
use Inline C => './check_line_c.c';

my $find    = "MATCH1";
my $search = "saasdadadadadasd";

my %sub_info = (
    c    => sub { check_line_c( $find, $search ) },
    perl => sub { check_line_perl( $find, $search ) },
);

timethese( 4_000_000, \%sub_info );

sub check_line_perl {
    my ($find, $search ) = @_;

    my $max_distance = 2;

    for my $offset ( 0 .. length($search) - length($find) ) {
        my $substr = substr( $search, $offset, length($find) );
        my $hd = hd( $find, $substr );
        if ( $hd <= $max_distance ) {
            return ( $hd, $substr );
        }
    }
    return ( undef, undef );
}

sub hd {
    return ( $_[0] ^ $_[1] ) =~ tr/\001-\377//;
}
```

where `check_line_c.c` is:

```c
void check_line_c( char* find, char * search ) {
    int max_distance = 2;
    int flen = strlen(find);
    int last_ind = strlen(search) - flen;

    SV *dis = &PL_sv_undef;
    SV *match = &PL_sv_undef;
    for ( int ind = 0; ind <= last_ind; ind++ ) 
    {
        int count = 0;
        for ( int j = 0; j < flen; j++ ) 
        {
            if ( find[j] ^ search[ind+j] ) count++; 
        }
        if ( count < max_distance )
        {
            match = newSV(flen);
            sv_catpvn(match, search+ind, flen );
            dis = newSViv(count);
            break;
        }
    }
    Inline_Stack_Vars;
    Inline_Stack_Reset;
    Inline_Stack_Push(sv_2mortal(dis));
    Inline_Stack_Push(sv_2mortal(match));
    Inline_Stack_Done;
}
```

The output is (Ubuntu Laptop using Intel Core i7-4702MQ CPU @2.20GHz):

```
Benchmark: timing 4000000 iterations of c, perl...
         c:  2 wallclock secs ( 0.76 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.76 CPU) @ 5263157.89/s (n=4000000)
      perl: 19 wallclock secs (18.30 usr +  0.00 sys = 18.30 CPU) @ 218579.23/s (n=4000000)
```

So this gives a 24-fold speedup for this case.

Comment: Thanks for inline example, a question -- are there big downsides/issues with simply using this (`Inline`) to use C?  I somehow thought that I'd have to go to XS and there's a bit more to do.

Comment: @zdim I am not sure, I just started writing C in Perl. I think you are right about that there is more work for the programmer to write directly in XS. But I have not programmed anything in XS yet. But I hope to learn it soon :)

Comment: I remember looking for how to use C in Perl and (I think) finding caveats with `Inline` (and feeling sorry about it since it's so straightforward). I also want to get into XS but never got around to it yet.

Comment: @zdim, It creates files at runtime, so you can run into permission problems. And like all self-installed modules, it requires a working compiler. That's about it. If you intended to distribute it, you'd make an actual XS module.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you very much. I somehow remember that there were caveats, it's very good to know that it's only this. (I will have to learn the XS finally though. Seems hairy and fun.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating a really bad hashing algorithm. Something nice and reversible and inefficient, like the sum of the characters. Or maybe the sum of unique values (1-4) represented by the characters.

Compute the target sums, and also compute the maximum allowed variance. That is, if the objective is a match with two substitutions, then what is the maximum possible difference? (4-1 + 4-1 = 6).

Then, for each "window" of text of the appropriate length in the target data file, compute a running score. (Add a character to the end, drop a character from the start, update the hash score.) If the score for a window is within the allowable range, you can do further investigation.

You might want to implement this as different passes. Possibly even as different stages in a shell pipeline or script. The idea being that you might be able to parallelize parts of the search. (For instance, all the match strings with the same length could be searched by one process, since the hash windows are the same.)

Also, of course, it is beneficial that you can keep your early work if your program crashes in the later stages. And you can even have the early parts of the process running while you are still developing the end stages.